# $_POST data is not passing to my function in Wordpress via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created an AJAX function in Wordpress. The function is called on form submission. The function is run, but it is not receiving any of the form data that I have submitted. What am I missing?

## PHP Function

I have added the PHP function here, which is called successfully via AJAX. This form creates a new user successfully, but only when I create the variables manually (eg. see $new_user_data['user_login'] = 'This Text Works';). For some reason, the $_POST data isn't coming through to the function.

```
add_action("wp_ajax_register_user", __NAMESPACE__ . "\\register_user");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user", __NAMESPACE__ . "\\register_user");

function register_user() {

  // NONCE VERIFICATION
  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "rtr_register_nonce")) {
  exit("Oops! This is embarassing!");

  }

 // Get all post data for the user.

 $new_user_data = array();
 $new_user_data['first_name'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['first-name']);
 $new_user_data['last_name'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['last-name']);
 $new_user_data['user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
 $new_user_data['user_pass'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['password']);

 $new_user_data['user_login'] = 'This Text Works';
 $new_user_data['role'] = 'subscriber';

 // Create the User
 $registered_user = wp_insert_user( $new_user_data );


 $result['user'] = $registered_user;

 // AJAX CHECK
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  $result = json_encode($result);
  echo $result;

} else {

  header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

}

die();


}
```

## JQuery

```
function registerUser(){

      var nonce = $('#regForm').attr("data-nonce");
      var formData = $('#regForm').serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: rtr_register_user.ajaxUrl,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {action: 'register_user', nonce: nonce, formData: formData},
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          $('#regForm').html('Your form has been submitted successfully');
        },


      });

    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
      // This function will figure out which tab to display
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("form-tab");
      // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
      if (n === 1 && !validateForm()) {
        return false;
      }
      // Hide the current tab:
      x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
      // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
      currentTab = currentTab + n;
      // if you have reached the end of the form... :
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        //...the form gets submitted:
        //document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        registerUser();
        return false;
      }
      // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
      showTab(currentTab);
    }

    $('#nextBtn').click(function () {
      nextPrev(1);
    });

    $('#prevBtn').click(function () {
      nextPrev(-1);
    });
```

## Form

```
<?php

$nonce = wp_create_nonce("rtr_register_nonce");
$link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=register_user&nonce='.$nonce);

?>

<form id="regForm" <?php echo 'data-nonce="' . $nonce . '"'; ?>   action="<?php echo $link; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">>

<div class="my-3 text-center">
<span class="form-step">1</span>
<span class="form-step">2</span>
</div>
<div class="form-tab">
<p><input name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
<p><input name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
<p><input name="dob" type="date" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
</div>

<div class="form-tab">
<p><input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
<p><input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
</div>

<div style="overflow:auto;">
<div style="float:right;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-brand" id="prevBtn">Previous</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-brand" id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Is ajax requested without an error? i doubt your ajax call was not triggerred

Comment: can you var_dump the content of $_POST and check what data is present there?

Comment: Ajax doesn't give me any errors @Thamaraiselvam

Comment: If I var_dump $_POST it gives me a 400 error in the console and nothing runs @flynorc - I'm actually writing that to the console as opposed to var_dump

Comment: Can you post here the request params of the Ajax?

Comment: I'm not sure what else I need @Thamaraiselvam ? What do you mean by request params? I've included all of the code (except for the wp_localize_script()

Comment: Open Developer tool (F12) -> network tab . Now trigger an ajax request now check that request params.

Comment: Your PHP seems fine, i doubt the request reaches the site

Comment: This isn't a PHP or Wordpress issue - at least from the code shown.  It is not clear what you want to do - a form POST or an ajax call via JS.....  Please show the code that calls the JS or try my 'looks like a simple case of form not being complete' answer.

Comment: Thanks @CFPSupport. The idea is to register a user via an AJAX form. The user is created when I call the function via AJAX - that is, it works to a point. But all of the $_POST data is empty. So, if I manually write the strings into the $new_user_data variable in the PHP function, it works as hoped. Otherwise the data is empty.

Comment: yes, which is exactly what everyone is saying - the PHP side looks great.  However, the HTML is not calling the JS and/or the form is not complete HTML (not sure which you want, but it looks like you need to do a JS "onclick" listener to get your buttons working or complete the form...)

Comment: Ok no worries @CFPSupport. Thanks. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are not triggering `registerUser()` check following script works fine for me

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('body').on('click', '#nextBtn', function() {
            registerUser();
        });
});

function registerUser(){

    var nonce = jQuery('#regForm').attr("data-nonce");
    var formData = jQuery('#regForm').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {action: 'register_user', nonce: nonce, formData: formData},
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          $('#regForm').html('Your form has been submitted successfully');
        },

    });
}
```

Comment: Ok I have it fixed now. Seems it was a combination of things. The AJAX was being called but the form wasn't being submitted. Thanks for helping to troubleshoot this.

Comment: you cannot do both at a time. do a form submit or ajax. anyway glad you found the problem.

Comment: I have posted a more complete answer below @GerritLuimstra. I'm happy to give credit to Thamaraiselvam for their input, but it is not complete. Although I'm not a big Stack Overflow user, so if this is not the way I should do things, then I'd be happy to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Mando, as you mentioned your answer, seems bit complicated, I took all your code and created a new plugin to check your script. at least do an upvote;), that would motivate me.  anyway, you found your way. happy coding.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I did upvote your answer. Not sure if it worked? The up arrow went orange.

Comment: Yeah, i got one. :+1:

Answer (score 0):

add method="post" to your 'form' - 'get' is the default https://stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2314401%2Fwhat-is-the-default-form-http-method&usg=AOvVaw1dKc3hW4K6r5SwQurLztBw

Comment: OP is sending request using ajax

Comment: not shown in the code.  From what is shown, there is not complete flow.

Comment: `From what is shown, there is not complete flow` Ya, we don't have any idea how OP is calling `registerUser()` method

Comment: yet OP IS calling the ajax.php from the form action........  (seems fixing the form method or the JS call is the answer....

Comment: I have added the code that calls registerUser() @A.Wolff

Comment: but, where does it call nextPrev?

Comment: I have also amended the form to include the method="post" which I was missing, but still no luck.

Comment: try changing the button type to "submit" - that clearly will submit the form.  You still have some work to get what you want, but that should move you to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

The "user_login" is a username of the user so probably it doesn't accepts space too.

See also [WP Insert Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)

Please try passing some username such as "custom_user" and see the result.

Hope this might work.

Comment: Sorry, I am actually using a single string there - 'test' for example. The WP Insert Post is working fine. It's the $_POST data that isn't coming through to the function.

Comment: Oh then you have to see the Ajax parameters and response.
Try debugging through var_dump( $results ) also and look to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was a bit of help from everyone here. But yes, I was calling the AJAX correctly, but not actually submitting the form. I added a .on(submit) to the form and then added a listener to the form to perform the AJAX call on submit. Here's the amendments below.

```
function nextPrev(n) {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("form-tab");

        if (n === 1 && !validateForm()) {
          return false;
        }

        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";

        currentTab = currentTab + n;

        if (currentTab >= x.length) {

        // ADDED THIS SUBMIT() HERE
          document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
          return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
      }


      // ADDED AN EVENT LISTENER TO TRIGGER THE AJAX CALL HERE
      $('#regForm').on('submit', function () {

          var nonce = $('#regForm').attr("data-nonce");
          var formData = $('#regForm').serialize();

          $.ajax({
            url: rtr_register_user.ajaxUrl,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              action: 'register_user',
              nonce: nonce,
              formData: formData
            },
            success: function (response) {
              console.log(response);
              $('#regForm').html('Your form has been submitted successfully');
            },


          });

        });
```

Comment: Actually, this works via the post method, but it actually isn't using AJAX. That is, it's still reloading the page??

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault();` to your on submit function

Comment: And don't forget to add the `e` parameter to the function on the top as a parameter ;)